# Continuous functions need hint

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

We have continuous functions $f,g:[0;\infty)\longrightarrow[0;\infty)$ with the following properties:

1. $f(0)=g(0)=0$
2. $g(x)\neq0$, for any $x>0$
3. $f(x+g(f(x)))=f(x)$, for any $x$

Prove that $f(x)=0$ for any $x$. I need only a hint how to start. So far I've tried something with a sequence with positive terms and limit $0$. I think that somehow we have to get to: $g(f(x))=0$ for any x, from where the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let any $x_0>0$. Show that there exist $x_1$ with $0<x_1\leq x_0$ such that $x_1+g(f(x_1))=x_0$, using the intermediate value theorem. Now let $u>0$, define a sequence $x_n$ with $x_0=u$ and $0<x_{n+1}\leq x_n$,  $x_{n+1}+g(f(x_{n+1}))=x_n$, and study $x_n$, and $f(x_n)$

Comment: For the Intermediate Value Theorem to work, don't we need the function to be defined on a compact interval?

Comment: You can take $[0,x_0]$

Comment: I got to the fact that $f(l)=0$ where $l$ is the limit of the sequence $x_n$.

Comment: OK...Now compare $f(x_n)$ and $f(x_{n+1})$.

Comment: Oh, so $f(x_n)$ is constant and all the terms are equal to zero, and since $x_0$ was chosen arbitrarily, the proof is complete, no? Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work out by assuming there is an $x_0 > 0$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$. Then what does that tell you about $f(x_0 + g(f(x_0)))$? How can you use this?

Comment: Then $g(f(x_0))\neq0$ and then $x_0+g(f(x_0))\neq x_0$, but when we apply $f(x)$, can't they become equal?